# Как заполнить массив членами арифметической прогрессии?

Tags: java, массивы

Примеры
Входные данные

```
8 4 5
```

Выходные данные

```
8 12 16 20 24

public static Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in); 
public static PrintStream out = System.out; 
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int c=in.nextInt();
    int b=in.nextInt();
    int x=in.nextInt();
    int a[];
     a= new int [x]; 

     for (int i=0;i<a.length;i++){
         a[x]= (int) (c+ b);    
         System.out.print(a.length);
     }


}
```

И как сделать так, чтобы начальное значение прогресcии было равно`int c`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В Вашем коде есть две существенные ошибки:

1. В цикле, очередное вычисленное значение прогрессии необходимо куда записать? – В `a[i]`, но никак не в `a[x]`. Потому что `x` – это исходная длина массива и она постоянна.
2. Как вычисляется `i`-ый член арифметической прогрессии? – Берется ее первый элемент и к нему прибавляется разность прогрессии, умноженная на ее `i-1` элемент. У Вас первоначальное значение `i=0`, поэтому вычислить `a[i]` можно как `c + b*i`.